# Union of many Counters

Tags: python, counter

What's the best way (in terms of readability and efficiency) of finding the union of a list of [Counters](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)?

For example, my list might look like this:

```
counters = [Counter({'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}),
            Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 5}),
            Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 4}),
            ...]
```

I want to calculate the union, i.e. `counters[0] | counters[1] | counters[2] | ...`.

One way of doing it would be this:

```
def counter_union(iterable):
    return functools.reduce(operator.or_, iterable, Counter())
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I think your approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: You might want a solution using `|=` if you have a lot of Counters.

Comment: @arshajii: Well, I was thinking that it'd be in-place, avoiding a potentially-quadratic amount of time spent making copies, but it doesn't look like Counter actually implements in-place versions of any operators.

Comment: That depends on the Python version:  inplace multiset methods were implemented for Counters starting in Python 3.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goodness, when did Python programmers become afraid of easy loops?  LOL.

```
result = Counter()
for c in counters:
    result |= c
```

There really aren't prizes in real life for squashing things into as few characters as theoretically possible.  Well, ya, there are in Perl, but not in Python ;-)

Later:  pursuant to user2357112's comment, starting with Python 3.3 the code above will do "in place" unions into `result`.  That is, `result` is truly reused, possibly growing larger on each iteration.

In any spelling of

```
counters[0] | counters[1] | counters[2] | ...
```

instead, the entire partial result so far keeps getting thrown away when the next partial result is computed.  That may - or may not - be a lot slower.

Comment: You're not by chance the creator of timsort, are you?

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't by chance ;-)

Answer (score 3):

user2357112 and Tim's comments made me realize that if you are going to use `reduce`, you should at least use `operator.ior`, not `operator.or_`.  In Python 3.3+, this will avoid creating a new counter for every iteration.

```
def counter_union(iterable):
    return functools.reduce(operator.ior, iterable, Counter())
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a loop is much more readable:

```
def counter_union(iterable):
    union = Counter()
    for counter in counters:
        union |= counter
    return union
```